# Audio jack ground to main earth ground, safe or not?

Tags: audio, ground, safety

My audio amplifier got some unclear noise from ground. The amplifier ground is connected to the player, and uses some decent RCA cables. I also tried to add a ground loop isolator to the RCA cables. None of them works.

Finally, a friend recommended me to try to connect the audio RCA jack ground to main earth ground, like in the picture shown below.

I tried this, and it works perfectly. But I just wonder: is there any potential safety issue?

[image]

Comment: I'd probably pull out the L and N prongs leaving just the E prong in place.

Comment: Connecting things to earth ground is usually *safer* than not connecting them; I'm no expert on safety but the worst you risk with this is creating a ground loop.

Comment: Oh, to add to what @Andyaka said, I believe it's possible to get plugs that have only the earth contact metal, with plastic L/N prongs, specifically for things like this. They're not my favorite way of grounding things, but they do work.

Comment: Motor Hum pickup is a common issue as well as SMPS noise.  Determining the path of noise, helps to choosing the best solution.

Comment: Isn't your amplifier equipped with a grounding terminal / screw?

Comment: @Jeroen3, yes, there is a audio ground terminal.

Answer (score 1):

It should be safe, as sometimes devices such as amplifiers without earth/ground that have only 2-prong mains plug can anyway be connected to other devices that are earth-grounded with a 3-prong mains plug.

Even if none of the devices are earth-grounded via mains plug so they are all floating, it can still be worth it to have extra potential-equalizing cable between devices, such as extra RCA cables. It keeps them at same potential, so it is slightly safer to disconnect and reconnect other cables, while the devices are connected to mains.

Nornally devices with 2-prong mains cables should be disconnected from mains while making other connections, to prevent damage from voltage potentials equalizing via RCA center pin or HDMI data pins. For this reason, even device manuals suggest disconnecting devices before making other connections.

Comment: thank you very much. the amp itself has a 3-prong mains plug, and an audio ground terminal on amp chassis. i guess the amp has some totally separated design on audio part and power part. the mains ground may only work for the power part for safty. and it connects to audio ground through other devices, like the same brand cd player.